# FluentValidation + blazor in dynamic form

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, fluentvalidation

I have a EditForm which contains a combobox. This combobox contains two possible options: Externo student or Interno student. Depending on what the user selects, the form asks to complete some mandatory fields in each case.
My issue is, that when I change between types of students in the combobox the validation errors show up. I understand that this is working fine, when I change the student type,  it reset the fields to empty, and then the validation is applied.

I've attached a picture of the form so I provide more context.

As you can see, this is the form when rendered for the first time. No validation errors are present.

[image]

Then if I change to **Interno** in the combobox the validation message is applied.

[image]

I'm using Blazor webassembly .NET 6.0 + FluentValidation.

**InscripcionModel.cs**

```
using FluentValidation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Inscripciones.Models
{
    public class InscripcionModel
    {
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Dni { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string LocalidadResidencia { get; set; }
        public string Ocupacion { get; set; }
        public string LocalidadTrabajo { get; set; }
        public int CursoId { get; set; }
        public List<int> Modulos { get; set; }
        public string? Observacion { get; set; }
        public string Captcha { get; set; }

        public InscripcionModel()
        {
            Modulos = new List<int>();
        }
    }

    public class ValidatorInscripcion : AbstractValidator<InscripcionModel>
    {
        public ValidatorInscripcion()
        {
            Regex regexDocumento = new(@"^[0-9]{7,8}$");
            Regex regexEmail = new (@"^((?!\.)[\w-_.]*[^.])(@\w+)(\.\w+(\.\w+)?[^.\W])$");

            When(alumno => alumno.Tipo.Equals("Externo"), () =>
            {
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Nombre).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo nombre no puede ser vacio");
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Apellido).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo apellido no puede ser vacio");
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Telefono).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo teléfono no puede ser vacio");
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.LocalidadResidencia).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo localidad residencia no puede ser vacio");
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Ocupacion).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo Ocupacion no puede ser vacio");
                RuleFor(alumno => alumno.LocalidadTrabajo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo localidad trabajo no puede ser vacio");
            });

            RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Dni)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("El campo documento no puede estar vacío")
                .Matches(regexDocumento)
                .WithMessage("El documento debe contener 7 u 8 caracteres numéricos");

            RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Email)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("El campo email no puede estar vacío")
                .Matches(regexEmail)
                .WithMessage("Ingrese un email del formato email@proveedor.com");

            RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Captcha)
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Resuelva el captcha para continuar");

            RuleFor(alumno => alumno.Modulos).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Debe elegir al menos un módulo del curso");

        }
    }
}
```

**FormularioInscripcion.razor**

```
<div class="spinner @(LoadingApiCall ? "show" : "hide")"></div>

<div class="@(ShowErrorMessage ? "show" : "hide")">
    <div class="alert alert-danger message" role="alert">
        <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Se ha producido un error, verifique su conexi&oacute;n de internet y recargue la p&aacute;gina
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@(CursosVacio ? "show" : "hide")">
    <div class="alert alert-info message" role="alert">
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> No existen cursos para el tipo de alumno @(inscripcionModel.Tipo.ToLower())
    </div>
</div>

<EditForm EditContext="@editContext"
          OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"
          id="inscripcionForm">
    <fieldset disabled="@DisableAllFields">
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label For="tipo" class="control-label control-label__lenga">
                Alumno
                <span class="alumno-aclaracion">
                    <i>
                        Marque <b>Interno</b> solo si es empleado del Ministerio P&uacute;blico Fiscal del Chubut caso contrario es <b>Externo</b>
                    </i>
                </span>
            </label>
            <InputSelect id="tipo"
                         Value="@inscripcionModel.Tipo"
                         ValueChanged="@((string tipo) => HandleTipoAlumno(tipo))"
                         ValueExpression="@(() => inscripcionModel.Tipo)"
                         class="form-control">
                <option value="Externo">Externo</option>
                <option value="Interno">Interno</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="dni" class="control-label control-label__lenga">
                    Documento
                    <span class="mandatory-field">*</span>
                </label>
                <InputText id="dni"
                           placeholder="Ingrese su DNI sin puntos"
                           class="form-control"
                           disabled="@CursosVacio"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Dni" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Dni)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="email" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Email donde le enviaremos las novedades <span class="mandatory-field">*</span></label>
                <InputText id="email"
                           placeholder="Ingrese un email del formato email@proveedor.com"
                           class="form-control"
                           disabled="@CursosVacio"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Email" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Email)" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="nombre" class="control-label control-label__lenga">
                    Nombre<span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span>
                </label>
                <InputText id="nombre"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsNombreInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsNombreInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.DisabledFieldNombreInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldNombrePlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Nombre" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Nombre)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="apellido" class="control-label control-label__lenga">
                    Apellido
                    <span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span>
                </label>
                <InputText id="apellido"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsApellidoInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsApellidoInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.disabledFieldApellidoInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldApellidoPlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Apellido" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Apellido)" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="telefono" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Tel&eacute;fono de contacto <span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span></label>
                <InputText id="telefono"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsTelefonoInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsTelefonoInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.DisabledFieldTelefonoInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldTelefonoPlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Telefono" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Telefono)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="localidadResidencia" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Localidad de residencia <span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span></label>
                <InputText id="localidadResidencia"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsLocalidadResidenciaInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsLocalidadResidenciaInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.DisabledFieldLocalidadResidenciaInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldLocalidadResidenciaPlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.LocalidadResidencia" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.LocalidadResidencia)" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="ocupacion" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Ocupaci&oacute;n <span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span></label>
                <InputText id="ocupacion"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsOcupacionInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsOcupacionInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.DisabledFieldOcupacionInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldOcupacionPlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Ocupacion" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Ocupacion)" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="localidadTrabajo" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Localidad donde trabaja <span class="@(inscripcionModel.Tipo == "Externo" ? "mandatory-field" : "hidden-mandatory")">*</span></label>
                <InputText id="localidadTrabajo"
                           disabled="@(DisabledFieldsLocalidadTrabajoInterno || CursosVacio)"
                           placeholder="@(DisabledFieldsLocalidadTrabajoInterno == true
                              ? @EstadosFormulario.DisabledFieldLocalidadTrabajoInterno
                              : @EstadosFormulario.FieldLocalidadTrabajoPlaceholder)"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.LocalidadTrabajo" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.LocalidadTrabajo)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cursos" class="control-label control-label__lenga">
                Cursos disponibles <span class="mandatory-field">*</span>
            </label>
            <select id="cursos"
                    class="form-control"
                    @onchange="HandleCursoChange"
                    disabled="@CursosVacio">
                @if (CursosVacio)
                {
                    <option selected disabled value="-1">
                        No existen cursos para alumnos @(inscripcionModel.Tipo.ToLower())
                    </option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option selected="@(inscripcionModel.CursoId == -1)" disabled value="-1">
                        Seleccione un curso
                    </option>

                    @foreach (var curso in CursosTipoAlumno)
                    {
                        <option value="@curso.CursoId">
                            @curso.Nombre
                        </option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        @if (inscripcionModel.CursoId != -1
        && CursoInfo != null
        && CursoInfo.Modulos != null
        && CursoInfo.Modulos.Length > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var modulo in CursoInfo.Modulos)
            {
                <input type="checkbox"
               id="@modulo.ModuloId"
               @onchange="(eventArgs => HandleCheckModulo(modulo.ModuloId, eventArgs.Value))" /> @modulo.NombreModulo
                <div class="moduloInfo"><i>@modulo.Descripcion</i></div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="modulosNota"><i>No se ha seleccionado un curso</i></span>
        }
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Modulos)" />

        <div class="form-group observacion-wrapper">
            <label for="observacion" class="control-label control-label__lenga">Observaciones </label>
            <InputTextArea id="observacion"
                           disabled="@CursosVacio"
                           class="form-control"
                           @bind-Value="inscripcionModel.Observacion" />
        </div>

        <div id="recaptcha_container"></div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => inscripcionModel.Captcha)" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    id="submitBtn"
                    disabled="@CursosVacio"
                    type="submit">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i>Enviar
            </button>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private InscripcionModel inscripcionModel = new()
        {
            Tipo = "Externo",
            CursoId = -1,
            Modulos = new List<int>()
        };

    private EditContext? editContext;

    private ValidationMessageStore? messageStore;

    private Curso? CursoInfo { get; set; }

    private int WidgetId;

    private bool CursosVacio { get; set; }

    private bool LoadingApiCall { get; set; } = true;

    private bool DisableAllFields { get; set; } = true;

    private bool ShowErrorMessage { get; set; } = false;

    private bool DisabledFieldsNombreInterno = false;
    private bool DisabledFieldsApellidoInterno = false;
    private bool DisabledFieldsTelefonoInterno = false;
    private bool DisabledFieldsLocalidadResidenciaInterno = false;
    private bool DisabledFieldsLocalidadTrabajoInterno = false;
    private bool DisabledFieldsOcupacionInterno = false;

    private List<Curso> cursos = new List<Curso>();

    private List<Curso> CursosTipoAlumno = new List<Curso>();

    private void HandleCursoChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args != null)
        {
            var cursoSelectedId = (args.Value?.ToString());
            if (cursoSelectedId != null)
            {
                var idx = Int32.Parse(cursoSelectedId);
                inscripcionModel.CursoId = idx;
                CursoInfo = cursos.Find(x => x.CursoId == idx);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleCheckModulo(int moduloId, Object checkboxState)
    {
        var moduloIdx = inscripcionModel.Modulos.FindIndex(x => x == moduloId);

        if ((bool)checkboxState)
        {
            if (moduloIdx == -1)
            {
                inscripcionModel.Modulos.Add(moduloId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (moduloIdx != -1)
            {
                inscripcionModel.Modulos.Remove(moduloId);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {
        ...
    }

    private void ResetFields(string tipo)
    {
        inscripcionModel.Tipo = tipo;
        inscripcionModel.Dni = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Email = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Nombre = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Apellido = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.LocalidadResidencia = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.LocalidadTrabajo = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Observacion = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Ocupacion = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.Telefono = string.Empty;
        inscripcionModel.CursoId = -1;
        inscripcionModel.Modulos = new List<int>();
        inscripcionModel.Captcha = string.Empty;
    }

    private void FiltrarCursoPorTipo(int tipoAlumno)
    {
        CursosTipoAlumno = new List<Curso>();

        if (tipoAlumno == 1)
        {
            CursosTipoAlumno = cursos;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Curso curso in cursos)
            {
                if (curso.TipoCurso == 0)
                {
                    CursosTipoAlumno.Add(curso);
                }
            }
        }
        CursosVacio = CursosTipoAlumno.Count == 0 ? true : false;
    }

    private async Task HandleTipoAlumno(string tipo)
    {
        ResetFields(tipo);

        CursoInfo = null;

        if (tipo == "Interno")
        {
            FiltrarCursoPorTipo(1);
            DisabledFieldsNombreInterno = true;
            DisabledFieldsApellidoInterno = true;
            DisabledFieldsTelefonoInterno = true;
            DisabledFieldsLocalidadResidenciaInterno = true;
            DisabledFieldsLocalidadTrabajoInterno = true;
            DisabledFieldsOcupacionInterno = true;
        }
        else
        {
            FiltrarCursoPorTipo(0);
            DisabledFieldsNombreInterno = false;
            DisabledFieldsApellidoInterno = false;
            DisabledFieldsTelefonoInterno = false;
            DisabledFieldsLocalidadResidenciaInterno = false;
            DisabledFieldsLocalidadTrabajoInterno = false;
            DisabledFieldsOcupacionInterno = false;
        }
        if (editContext != null)
        {
            editContext.MarkAsUnmodified();
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            editContext.Validate();
        }

        await JS.InvokeAsync<int>("reset_recaptcha");
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(inscripcionModel);

        messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);

        LoadingApiCall = DisableAllFields = true;

        var CaptchaSiteKey = Settings.CatpchaSiteKey;

        await Task.Delay(1);

        try
        {
            var cursosApi = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Curso[]>
                (Settings.API_URL_GET);

            if (cursosApi != null)
            {
                cursos = cursosApi.ToList();

                FiltrarCursoPorTipo(0);

                LoadingApiCall = DisableAllFields = false;
                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoadingApiCall = false;
            ShowErrorMessage = true;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
       if (firstRender)
       {
          WidgetId = await JS.InvokeAsync<int>
             ("render_recaptcha", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), 
         "recaptcha_container", Settings.CatpchaSiteKey);
       }
       await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

   [JSInvokable, EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
   public void CallbackOnSuccess(string response)
   {
     inscripcionModel.Captcha = response;
   }

  [JSInvokable, EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
  public void CallbackOnExpired()
  {
    inscripcionModel.Captcha = "";
  }
}
```

When I change the first combobox, the method **HandleTipoAlumno** is called. The idea is that the form should be reset to the initial state (no validations applied. The form is supposed to be untouched or *pristine*)

I tried using the following:

```
            editContext.MarkAsUnmodified();
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            editContext.Validate();
```

After changing the type of student, I marked all fields as *unmodified* or *clean*, then I notify that the validation has changed and finally apply the validation of the editform.
This is not working, the error messages are still showing up.

**Sidenote**: I also tried to re-instantiate the editform model (editContext = new EditContext(model)) as the last line in **HandleTipoAlumno** method, that approach is working fine, the validation errors are gone and the fields are reset, but my captcha is not rendering once I reinstantiate the editcontext.
The first render in method (**OnAfterRenderAsync**) is rendering the captcha fine, but then when changing the combobox it vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `editContext` after programmatically changing the fields (`ResetFields`)

```
editContext = new EditContext(inscripcionModel);
```

Comment: Check the Sidenote in the question. I have an issue with captcha if I do that.

Comment: Which captcha are you using? Have you tried also resetting the captcha after the edit context? `WidgetId = await JS.InvokeAsync<int>("render_recaptcha", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), "recaptcha_container", Settings.CatpchaSiteKey);`

Comment: I'm using GoogleRecaptcha-V2. I've already tried that, and also resetting manually with reset_recaptcha function, but it is not showing after changing the selected element in the combobox.